# Permission denied : collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have just installed Visul code.But I can't run any code. When I try to run anything this happend. I have recently installed windows 11 from windows 10. I had no problem running on windows 10.
I have reinstalled this several time.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj5HN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SupRB.png)

How to solve this probelem.

Comment: Rename the file to not include spaces.

Comment: With some effort, VS Code can be configured to handle spaces in filenames. But the easiest fix is to use underscores instead, like you would on Linux.

Comment: Computers don't *understand*. You put a space in a file name, the computer thinks it's two filenames, even though there exists a file with the space in the name. Simple answer is to not use filenames with spaces in them, or use quotes to surround the file name. Then the computer will understand.

Answer (score 1):

You have files with spaces and try to build them without quotes. So, the compiler/builder treats each space as a delimiter => tries to find files as "Find", "Remainder.cpp", etc. Try to remove spaces from file names or use quotes.